# Syntax error using !(lo) syntax when running in script

Tags: bash

Running on the command line:

```
tmp=$(cd /sys/class/net; echo !(lo))
echo $tmp
eth0
```

Is OK. But running in script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp=$(cd /sys/class/net; echo !(lo))
echo $tmp
```

Outputs the error:

```
./test.sh: command substitution: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '('
./test.sh: command substitution: line 3: 'cd /sys/class/net: echo !(lo))'
```

What is happening here? Why does it work *correctly* in the bash shell, but not in script?

Comment: `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: BTW, lists should generally be stored in arrays, not string variables -- `shopt -s nullglob; devices=( !(lo) ); echo "Non-local devices:" >&2; printf ' - %q\n' "${devices[@]}"` is more robust than your original code against surprising device names -- and keep in mind that userspace code *can* rename devices.

Comment: dump this into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and it may help out a bit.

Comment: @JNevill, ...unfortunately, shellcheck doesn't appear to check for extglob use without explicit enablement. Sure, there are other issues, but the core one isn't caught.